# React Native trigger useEffect from changes in AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I'm working on a react native authentication screen. I'm storing the token in AsyncStorage (yea I know it's not the best solution).
So what's happening is when I log in, the token is stored, but the getItem on my Authentication.js screen is not being triggered, and the profile screen is not being called.
If I log in and then manually refresh the app, I am redirected to the profile screen.

Login.js

```
function Login({navigation}) {
  const [signIn, {data}] = useMutation(USER_SIGNIN_MUTATION);
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  function handleLogIn() {
    signIn({
      variables: {
        email: userName,
        password: password,
      },
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data != null) {
      setToken();
    }
  });

  const setToken = async () => {
    try {
      console.log('before');
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', data.signIn.token);
      console.log('after');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return(
     ...
  )
}
```

Authentication.js

```
function Authentication() {
  const [localToken, setLocalToken] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      try {
        console.log('before get');
        const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        if (userData !== null) {
          setLocalToken(true);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    fetchUser();
  }, [localToken]);

  console.log(`auth screen - ${localToken}`);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {localToken === true ? <ProfileStack /> : <AuthStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default Authentication;
```

also same happens with the logout function when fired. (the function runs, but I need to refresh the app to get back to the login screen)

Profile.js

```
function Profile({navigation}) {
  function signOut() {
    logOut();
  }

  const logOut = async () => {
    try {
      console.log('before clear');
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem('token');
      console.log('after clear');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

I'm grateful for any insight on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      try {
        console.log('before get');
        const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        if (userData !== null) {
          setLocalToken(true);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    fetchUser();
  }, [localToken]);
```

Here you added the localToken variable in the dependency array of the useEffect. So you are basically saying: run this effect only if the localToken variable changes. But you change that from within the effect only. So try to remove it and keep the dependency as []. This way the effect will run when the component is rendered.

About the fact that you have to refresh the page, it is important to understand why this happens.

```js
  <NavigationContainer>
      {localToken === true ? <ProfileStack /> : <AuthStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Here you are rendering ProfileStack or AuthStack based on the localToken value. When you logout, you remove the token from the AsyncStorage but this is not enough. You actually need to trigger a rerender in the Authentication component so the localToken is reevaluated. Basically, when you logout you also need to set setLocalToken(false). So you need to access setLocalToken function from the Profile component. You can pass this function as a prop or better you can use [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: after removing `localToken` from the dependency array, i still have to refresh the app to get the screen to switch.

Comment: Is this happening even for login? Or only for the logout?

Comment: its happening for both.

Comment: I edited my initial response where I explain why this is happening for the logut. The same is true for the login.

Comment: that makes sense. thank you for the explanation there.